# MSVCR80.DLL Reference in C++ project , VS2005

Tags: .net, c++

I have to modify in an old project , I just comment a line in a C++ 2.0 project with VS2005, when i build the project , i see on .net reflector a reference to MSVCR80.DLL, but on the old DLL, wich is on production, there is nor reference to this DLL

how can i remove this reference?

Thank's in advance

Comment: Is this a C++/CLI project? That's not particularly clear from your question. However, if it weren't, I'm not sure how or why you're looking at it with .NET Reflector.

Answer (score 0):

MSVCR80.DLL provides the C runtime.  Since you compile with a different compiler you have a different runtime library to work with.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for starting references to learn more. You could configure your project to link the C runtime statically, and that would get rid of the DLL dependency.

Answer (score 0):

A static library by default links to the dynamic runtime, which is why your code has a dependency on msvcr80.dll. Visual C++ programs must link to a runtime. You can change your static library to use a static runtime to remove the dependency.

Do it in `Configuration Properties | C/C++ | Code Generation | Runtime Library setting`.
if it is set to `Multi Threaded Debug DLL` then set it to `Multi Threaded`.... Or just select the `NON-DLL` version from available list

Your code probably depends on mfc80.dll because you have Configuration Properties | General | Use of MFC set to one of the MFC options.

Comment: Strictly managed applications don't have to link to a version of the CRT. That's why it's important to figure out what kind of app the asker actually has. According to the question, he's examining it in .NET Reflector. Which doesn't make a lot of sense for an unmanaged C++ application, MFC or otherwise.